# MVC Post Request how to get Request Content if it's different to that expected by the Default ModelBinder

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this MVC WebApi action:

```
PostTrips(List<Trip> trips)
```

When a list of trips is sent through everything works fine. If, however, someone is trying to post incorrect data, e.g just an object `{}` then trips is null - this is fine, but I would like to log the data that the user tried to push.

I tried to get it using `string requestData = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;` but it can only be called once, and I guess the default model binder is calling it to try an map it to my `List<Trip>`, as when I call it, the result is always `null`, even though I know I'm passing something in.

Does anyone know of another way to get the posted data again?

Comment: All post data I believe (apart from files) is serialised into Dictionary<KeyValuePair<string, object>> and is stored in the Request.Form.  Have you tried looking in there?

Comment: No there's nothing in there unfortunately. Keys = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this my removing the parameter `List<Trip> trips` from the action so I had:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostTrips()
{
}
```

This bypasses the default model binder and allows you to get the unmodified request content using:

```
string requestContent = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

You can then do what ever you need with this - I wanted to log the data for error tracking.

To create the actual `List<Trip> trips` I then used Newtonsoft.Json to deserialise the string into a list:

```
List<TravelTrackerTrip> appTrips = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TravelTrackerTrip>>(requestContent);
```

Full example:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostTrips()
{
    HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();

    List<Trip> appTrips = null;
    string requestContent = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    try
    {
        appTrips = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Trip>>(requestContent);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //ERROR LOGGING HERE...

        //QUIT - Return failure response
    }

    try
    {
        //Success - do whatever we need
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //ERROR LOGGING HERE...

        //QUIT - Return failure response
    }

    //Return success response
}
```